# Who were the kings who ruled in the 2nd manvanter?

Tags: kings

I'm requesting a list of kings of the 2nd manvanter who ruled during Satya Yuga, Treta Yuga, and Dwapar Yuga.

Comment: That type of information unfortunately does not exist. I can tell you who the Indra was who presided in 2nd Manvantara. However, I do not believe that there are any scriptures of the names of kings that ruled during the 2nd Manvantara.

Comment: Furthermore, I do not believe that there were any kings ruling in the 2nd Manvantara. Each Manvantara is 330 million years, and the 2nd Manvantar was 1.65 billion years ago. The only entities alive, let alone kings, were the gods and the asuras. Maybe Maharishis belonging to the higher lokas (i.e Jana Loka and Tapa Loka.)

Answer (score 1):

If by the second Manvantara you mean the Svarocisha Manvantara, then the Markandeya Purana lists an elaborate account.

First it is mentioned that his three sons are given their kingdom:

> And then three sons were born to Svarocis, Vijaya, and Merunanda, and mighty Prabhāva; and Indīvara’s daughter Manoramā gave birth to **Vijaya**, Vibhāvarī to **Merunanda**, and Kalāvatī to **Prabhāva**. And by the power of the knowledge named Padmini, which accomplishes all pleasures, he their father built three cities for them. Now he gave a noble city named Vijaya on a hill in Kāmarūpa in the Eastern region **to his son Vijaya** at first; and he made **Merunanda’s city** the famous one in the north, called Nandavatī, which is begirt with lofty ramparts and walls; and he made **Kalāvatī’s son Prabhāva** to dwell in the famous city Tāla which is situated in the Southern region. Having thus settled his sons in their cities, he, the manly hero, sported with those his wives in charming highlands.
>
> [Markandeya Purana chapter 66](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117124.html)

In the concluding chapter, seven sons are mentioned, without giving a full list:

> The gods in that period were the Pārāvatas and also the Tuṣitas. O brāhman; and in Svārociṣa’s period the Indra was famed as Vipaścit. Ūrja, Tamba and Prāṇa, Dattoli and Ṛṣabha, Niścara and Cārvavīrat were the seven ṛṣis in that period. And **seven sons had that high souled Manu, Caitra, Kimpuruṣa, &c.**, very valiant, guardians of the earth. So long as his Manvantara lasted, all this earth was enjoyed among the outspreadings of his family. That was the second Manvantara.
>
> [Markandeya Purana chapter 67](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117126.html)

The Vishnu Purana (Book 3 chapter 1) mentions the same 2 sons.

Caitra mentioned here is an important name, since we have mention on the Caitravaṃśa (“the linenage of Caitra”) in the Devi-bhagavata-purana:

> 6-13. Nārāyaṇa said :-- O Nārada! This Eighth Manu had been, before, in the time of Svārociṣa Manu (the second Manu), **a famous king, known by the name of Suratha**, born of the family of **Caitra**, and very powerful. He could well appreciate merits, clever in the science of archery, amassed abundance of wealth, a generous donor, a very liberal man and he was a celebrated poet and honoured by all. He was skilled in all arts of warfare with weapons and indomitable in crushing his foes.
>
> [Devibhagavata-purana book 10 chapter 10](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57374.html)

Actually, Suratha is prophecised to be the next Manu (the eighth), name Savarni:

> The Devī said :-- “O King! By My boon, you will get your foeless kingdom in this very birth as well as the Jñānam that removes ignorance. O King! I will tell you also what you will be in the next birth. Hear. In your next birth, you will be the son of the Sun and be famous as Sāvarṇi Manu. By My boon you will be the Lord of the Manvantara, become very powerful and you will get good many sons.” Thus granting him this boon, the Devī disappeared. By the Grace of the Devī, **Suratha became the Lord of the Manvantara**. O Sādhu! Thus I have described to you the birth and deeds of Sāvarṇi. He who hears or reads this anecdote with devotion, will be a favourite of the Devī.
>
> [Devibhagavata-purana book 10 chapter 12](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57376.html)

The story of Suratha being a devotee of the Goddess is corroborated in the Shiva Purana, making mention of even more kings living in that era:

> Formerly in the Svārociṣa Manvantara there was a king Viratha. **Suratha his son was of great strength and exploit**. He was very munificent, truthful, efficient in duties, a devotee of the goddess, an ocean of kindness and the protector of his subjects. While he was thus ruling over the earth, with the brilliance of Indra, nine other kings became desirous of seizing his land. They laid siege to his capital Kolā. The king had a terrible war with them.
>
> [Shiva Purana book 5 chapter 41](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226605.html)

The Padma Purana names four sons of Svarocisha:

> These, having brought about secondary creation, reached the highest place. Thus is described the Svāyambhuva period; after this comes the Svārociṣa. Svārociṣa’s four sons, having god-like lustre were: **Nabha, Nabhasya, Bhāvana, and Kiītivardhana**. The seven sages were: Datta, Agni, Cyavana, Stambha, Prāṇa, Kaśyapa and Arvābṛhaspati.
>
> [Padma Purana book chapter 7](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364127.html)

The Brahmanda Purana mentions the seven sons of Svarocisa as:

> The following are declared as the nine sons of Svārociṣa Manu, viz. **Caitra, Kimpuruṣa, Kṛtānta, Vibhṛta, Ravi, Bṛhaduktha, Nava, Satu and Śruta.** They were the perpetuators of the line of lord Manu. They have been thus enumerated in the Purāṇas. This is the second Manvantara.
>
> [Brahmanda Purana book 2 chapter 36](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362854.html)

The Vayu Purana also mentions seven sons of Svarocisa as follows:

> **Caitra, Kaviruta, Kṛtānta, Ravi, Bṛhat, Guha, Nava and Śubha: these nine are rememberd as the sons of Svārociṣa Manu** who established his race. They have been enumerated in the Purāṇa. Such is the second Manvantara.
>
> [Vayu Purana book 2 chapter 1](https://archive.org/details/the-vayu-purana-part-2-ancient-indian-tradition-and-mythology/page/n19/mode/2up)

Chapter 6 of the Vayu Purana contains an interesting story on how the Devas are born in the seven Manvantaras. In the Svārociṣa Manvantara, they were
born as the sons of Svārociṣa and Tuṣitā.

Another story regarding King Ritadhvaja from Saurashtra in the Svarocisha Manvantara can be found in the Skanda Purana:

> [...] A great deal of time elapsed and the net became tattered and worn out. Since that worn out net did the work of a flag on the top of the auspicious mansion the fish-killer was born on the earth as a king, thanks to the greatness of the flag. The intelligent king was **well-known as Ṛtadhvaja in Saurāṣṭra country**. He moved about all over the earth in a chariot with the shining flag fluttering. He was valorous. He ruled the kingdom. Yet he was overwhelmed with a great desire for sensual pleasures. He raised a shining flag, a clean banner of variegated colours, over the abode of Śaṃbhu. Although he was very rich and powerful, he did nothing else.
>
> [Skanda Purana 7.1 chapter 294](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc627082.html)

Further, it is mentioned in this Purana that, at the commencement of the first Yuga of the Svarocisa Manvantara, "crores of kings" have come and gone since Indradyumna’s visit to Brahma:

> In the course of the time when the songs were sung, much of your time has passed. Indeed a Manvantara consists of seventy-one divine Yugas (i.e. cycles of four Yugas according to human reckoning). Your dynasty has become extinct. **Crores and crores of kings have passed away. The Lord and the ultimate Mansion—these two alone remain. Now it is the first Yuga of the Second Manu Svārociṣa**. Since you have stayed near me, there is neither death nor old age (to you). There is no change of seasons nor the flow of time. Hence, O great king, go to the earth. Make the Lord and the Mansion your own and come here quickly. Or I shall go over there immediately after you.
>
> [Skanda Purana book 2.2 chapter 23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370743.html)